# Coloring a Row in an NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What I am looking to do is set the background color of the selected row in an NSTableView when a I button is clicked.
I've seen other cases where people have used `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:` and `setBackgroundColor:` but I don't think that will work in my situation where I want it to happen when a button is clicked.

I know that I can find the selected row with NSTableView's `selectedRow` method and set the Background color for a cell with `setBackgroundColor:`, but what I don't know how to do is get from a NSInteger for the selected row to an NSCell to set the background color of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSTableView` uses only one instance of `NSCell` for each column. When drawing the contents, the cell is updated for each row. That’s why there’s no method to get a cell for a specified row—you have to modify the cell in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:`.

You can tell the table view to update only one row using `reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:`.

Comment: I've just tried this http://grab.by/1CoC but it colors every single row grey not just the one I reload.

Comment: 1. Don't use `int`. Use `NSInteger`. 2. Try doing what Nikolai said. (Note that it requires Snow Leopard.) 3. Make your `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:` method check both whether the row is selected and whether the user has clicked the button.

Comment: 1. Ok. 2 & 3. I can't do exactly what he said because I have an NSOutlineView, or can I do it because NSOutlineView inherits from NSTableView?

Comment: Of course, since an NSOutlineView is an NSTableView, you can do with it whatever an NSTableView can do. (Inheritance == "is a")

Comment: Ok, this is what I've got now, http://grab.by/1Dp2, However I am unsure how to tell whether the user has clicked the button.

Comment: Have a Boolean variable, initialize it to false (`NO`), then set it to `YES` when the user presses the button. Reset it to `NO` at an appropriate later time.

Comment: Also, `=` is the assignment operator, not the equality operator. You should turn on the warning for that in Xcode so that the compiler will complain any time you make this mistake.

Comment: Ok, here's what's new, http://grab.by/1Dvd, but it doesn't actually trigger the delegate method.

Answer (score 7):

To set background color to `NSTableview` Row

```
  - (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell1 forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row 
{
      if(row==1)
         [cell1 setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
      else if(row==2||row==3)
         [cell1 setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
      else
         [cell1 setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
}
```

using this method we can give different color to each row..
Make sure `drawsBackground` is enabled on the `NSTextFieldCell` otherwise this will have no effect!

Answer (score 6):

If you simply want to change the color of an entire selected row:

```
NSInteger selectedRow = [self.nsTableView selectedRow];
NSTableRowView* rowView = [self.nsTableView rowViewAtRow:selectedRow makeIfNecessary:NO];
[rowView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
```

glhf

Comment: Only if you're using a view-based table.  If we're talking about cell-based tables, as I think we are, then the rowViewAtRow:... method will always return nil.