# Can't programmatically refresh NStableView cell text colour

Tags: objective-c

I'm colouring `NSTableView` cell text. I want to specify text colour when I perform double click on the cell. Problem is that this colour change is not performed immediately after I performed double click. I need to perform some more action to get my cell text coloured e.g. selecting another cell, switching to another app..

I tried to update the cell itself:

`[self.tableView updateCell:[self.tableView selectedCell]];`

Also tried this:

`[self.tableView reloadData];`

But it didn't help. All I want is to tell `NSTableView` to perform refresh so

`-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`

for each cell will be called.

Comment: How are you coloring the text?

Comment: `if (condition) { [cell setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]]; }` inside `-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a cell based tableview, right?

Comment: Yes, it is cell based.

Comment: Have you checked out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028236/coloring-a-row-in-an-nstableview) post? It claims that `reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:` should work.